# Flutter app is not loading on IOS device after sometime

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am learning Dart/Flutter and running into an interesting issue with real IOS device.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_statusbar_manager/flutter_statusbar_manager.dart';

void main() {
  bool _statusBarHidden = true;
  FlutterStatusbarManager.setHidden(_statusBarHidden);
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage()
  ));
}
```

home_page.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new DecoratedBox(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('assets/images/background

.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Very simple app, just display an image as a background. So i have deployed and installed the app in a real IOS device (iPad 4th). Its looking great. I hit the app icon on the device and display exactly that what i am expecting.

However, after several day, the app is not working anymore. When i open the app, its pop-ing up and disappear right away back to main screen of the iPad. i keep doing that but nothing happens. Its totally scratched. 
I have tried to remove the app and install it again. its running great and scratch again after sometime using it.

Any ideal, it makes me worry about Flutter or i might doing something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple developer membership?  If you are using a free membership, the app stops working after a few days and you need to re-install it.

Comment: Ahh. I see. i didn't know about that. I am using free membership. Thanks